# JSF: How do I include parameters in an action method's return string?

Tags: jsf, navigation

I'm writing an action method that will store a new object in a database. Once this is done, I want to navigate to view that newly created object. To do this, I was planning to include a querystring or some sort of parameter in the return String of the action method, but I can't figure out how. If I append a query string manually, it appears that it's being ignored. Also, manually adding parameters by concatenating strings doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Is it possible to do this in a type-safe manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I've always handled this is to get a reference to the bean which provides the content for the page you'll be displaying, and just set its properties directly.  The navigation string returned from an action method isn't meant for passing parameters, but you don't need it to; all they'd be used for is setting bean properties anyway.