# Send parameter via action bean method

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251941/jsf-how-do-i-include-parameters-in-an-action-methods-return-string) but my method is a logout where I need to invalidate session so I cannot set bean property.
I just want to pass user language.

```
 public String logout() {
    Locale locale = userProfile.getLocale();

    // invalidate http session
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();

    return "logout";
    //I need something like 
    //return "logout?locale="+locale.getLanguage();
}
```

---

EDIT: solved returning this:

```
return "/logout.xhtml?faces-redirect=true&amp;include-view-params=true&amp;locale=" + locale.getLanguage();
```

Comment: XML entities like `&amp;` are not required in Java source files.

Comment: Answers should be in answers, not in updates of the question